# Force to backtrack in Prolog

Tags: list, prolog

I want to code a prefix function with prolog, but it does not work.

Here's my code:

```
prefix(P,[X|_]) :-
    P == X.
```

And I want that this input results to `true`:

```
?- prefix([1,2],[1,2,3,4]).
```

The problem is that I want that the `X` goes back and tries to get another value to result to `true`.

Can you show me where the mistake is?

Answer (score 3):

Here's my advice:

- Explore and use tried-and-tested library predicates: don't reinventing the wheel!
- Read the [Prolog prologue](https://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/iso-prolog/prologue) for precise definitions of these commonly used predicates: [`member/2`](https://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/iso-prolog/prologue#member), [`append/3`](https://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/iso-prolog/prologue#append), [`length/2`](https://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/iso-prolog/prologue#length), [`between/3`](https://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/iso-prolog/prologue#between), [`select/3`](https://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/iso-prolog/prologue#select), [`succ/2`](https://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/iso-prolog/prologue#maplist), [`maplist/2..8`](https://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/iso-prolog/prologue#maplist).
- Try to *not use meta-logical* Prolog facilities—like `(==)/2`—if you don't have to.
- As a beginner, particularly *focus on the pure monotonic subset of Prolog*.

End of preaching:)

---

Let's get back to the question! Based on [`append/3`](https://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/iso-prolog/prologue#append) we can define `prefix_of/2` like this:

```
prefix_of(Prefix,List) :- 
   append(Prefix,_Suffix,List).
```

Sample queries:

```
?- prefix_of([1,2],[1,2,3,4]).
true.

?- prefix_of(Prefix,[1,2,3,4]).
  Prefix = []
; Prefix = [1]
; Prefix = [1,2]
; Prefix = [1,2,3]
; Prefix = [1,2,3,4]
; false.
```

Answer (score 2):

P is a list, while X is an element. So, some 'deep' change to your code is required. Maybe

```
prefix([X|Ps], [X|Qs]) :- prefix(Ps, Qs).
prefix([], _).
```

Answer (score 1):

By your définition, `prefix([1,2],[1,2,3,4])` is equivalent to `[1,2] == 1`, which obviously fails.

What you probably want is the equivalence with `prefix([2], [2,3,4])`